# how to set image as background in launch.storybord + xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

in recent release of xamarin launch screen can be designed from storyboard instead of old approach where we were adding all splash screen images according to wise.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

from this link get to know how can set launchscreen using storyboard.

so my question is how can i set image as background to storyboard dont want background colour.

i need image as background on which i can put logo image and label.

so is it possible?if yes then how.

please help.

[image: see here]

Comment: add a UIImageView as subview which fills with the screen first.

Comment: there is no such control i can see in toolbox like UIImageView :(

Comment: Oh,in VS it named `Image View`

Comment: yes.i tried that.i took imageview control on storybord.and astreched to cover storybord.but at runtime it dont fiil whole screen

Comment: what i am doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `top,bottom,leading,trailing` constraints on the imageView.

1. Select `Constraint edit mode` ,and click twice to show the point on side which ca be dragged to set the constraint.

   [image]
2. Modify the constraint value to 0(in Property menu).

   [image]
3. Do the same work on the four constraints.

   [image]

Refer to [Auto Layout with the Xamarin Designer for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/)

Comment: please have a look at screenshot that i added in question.

Comment: do i need to add my image with this name format and sizes as shown in screenshot first???

Comment: No need.This is old approach we set for splash screen.  When you are using launch storyboard, you just need to add image to your project regardless of it name format.

Comment: that image will work with all devise size and for both direction?

Comment: Actually ,the launch.storayboard is designed for this.  We don't need to add so many image files any more. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Comment: Refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/storyboards/Unified_Storyboards/#Dynamic_Launch_Screens

Comment: If you have any problem , let me know. and if it helps, consider accepting it as answer, Thanks.

Comment: yeah..sure..thank you so much  for your valuable time :)